# mapbox comparsion filter not working on numbers

Tags: filter, comparison, mapbox-gl-js

i have tried to find anything about my problem online but unfortunately i had no luck finding anything that would help me.

i have a custom javascript map built with mapbox-gl-js.
the map shows real estate objects which can be filtered by country, city etc. using a custom built filter bar. now on this filter bar there are dropdown fields and two input fields. the filters i built for the dropdown fields work just fine. in the code use equal-to-comparsions for this task.

the two input fields are there to filter the maximum price and a minimum square meters - here i use the less or equal than and greater or equal than  comparsion filters.

for some reason these two filter's won't work as desired. for example if i filter for objects with max price 1000000 objects with greater price still show.

this is how my filter would look like in JSON:

```js
["all",["<=","preis",1000000]]
```

this is how the features look like:

```js
feature = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [...]
  },
  "properties": {
    [...],    
    "preis": 20000000,
    [...]
  }
}
```

i have also tried to reproduce this in a simple test map with simple objects - there the problem also exists.

does anyone have a clue why this is acting up on me or has anyone had or got an familiar issue?

thanks and br, John

Comment: are you sure your feature properties aren't actually being stored as strings? if you could post a minimal jsfiddle/jsbin it will be easier to diagnose.

Comment: hi mollymerp and thanks for taking your time

i can verify with debugger that the value in my filter is integer(number). according to mapbox gl js documentation it is possible to pass values with the type 'number':

[link](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#types-filter)

the example on that page also uses a numeric value.
i've tried with string compare but that won't work either.

Comment: can you include an example on jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: hi and sorry for taking so long...
i placed a flattened version of my code in a jsfiddle and figured it works there. i will have to do further debugging later on the complete code
i will get back to you thanks for now!